# How to repair cement/flowable-fill slab cracks

Tags: slab, cement

I have a 5o yr old condo. The second floor is a cement or flowable-fill slab. There are cracks in areas and a pit in one area.

Can I repair the pit and cracks or do I need to tear it all out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would first determine how thick it is in order to see if it is the whole floor or just a top coat layer.  Do this by drilling a core to determine the thickness and what is underneath that layer of cement.

Comment: It's about 2 or 3 inches max, closer to two.

Comment: Is the exposed floor in a bathroom that had water damage and the rest of the second floor appears to be in good condition?  It appears that you have removed a layer of plywood that was installed over plywood runners. The plywood runner closest to the concert pad appears to be broken. Was this broken during the removal?

Comment: I removed nothing. Just pulled up the carpet last week and found it as it. There is a bath upstairs but no signs of water damage anywhere. Just the cracks in the master and guest bedrooms. No cracks in the walls or near the windows. The bath is tiled, so I'd have to pull all those out to see the state of the floor there.

Answer (score 1):

I mis-interpreted your picture.  So what we are seeing is a level concrete floor with carpet tack strips in the foreground area.  But I'm not fully understanding the foreground of the picture you provided.
It appears that we can see the edge of the concrete pad in the middle of the floor.

[image]

If you had no issue with the floor with carpet in the past, I would just leave it as it is if you are planning to recarpet. 
 
The thickness would indicate it is cement. Repairing the bad spot like under your foot will not stop all the other fine cracks from continuing to crack further. It took 50 years to reach this point. If you took it out, you would almost have to do another concrete pour to bring it up to the level of the other rooms, i.e., bath rooms to the same level. Otherwise you would have to tear it out for all of the second floor to bring them all to the same level. 
Unless you have some serious concerns, I would leave it as is. 
Will you still be there in 10-15 years?

If repairs/sealing of the cracks is to be done, I would go with two types of products, liquid/self leveling for the thinner-fine cracks and a heavier product for the larger cracks.  For the liquid, look at products similar to [Dap 37584 product](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Gray-Concrete-Patch/3024887) and for the larger cracks, [Dap Ready-Mixed Patch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Gray-Concrete-Patch/1085955).

Comment: You are correct. Those are carpet tacks you see. The pic was taken at the top of stairway where the concrete slab begins, the second floor.

Comment: What type of flooring are you planning to place on top of it?

Comment: I want to recarpet.

Comment: Can I repair the bad spots and just recarpet or do you think this will progressively worsen to the point I'll have to just take out the floor. Is this flowable fill or cement? I'm a novice, so pardon my lack of knowledge.

Comment: If I tore out the cement, I would not re-pour a new slab.

Comment: What am I looking at in terms of cost if I tore it all out vs repairing it?

Comment: I will have to let others weigh in on repairing it.  I do not believe any type of repair is going to stop further cracking.  A level setting layer would require that all cracks to be sealed and blocked off.  I do not know if it will be strong enough to prevent further cracking in the concrete beneath it.  The main issue I see is that the floor appears to have many fine cracks throughout the floor so repairing the large cracks beyond just sealing them do not seem cost effective.

Comment: Thank you for you input. Much appreciated. One question I failed to answer. You asked if I'd be in the place another 10 years or so? Answer: more than likely. Not sure though. Some have said to do the best you can with filling the cracks but otherwise leave it.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the previous comment, just sealing the large cracks, but not removing large chunks or sections, that would be the limit of my repairs.

Comment: Would applying a Crack Lock treatment at least add a level of stability to the cracks, perhaps limiting further cracking?